# Dog too scared to come inside after incident

Tags: dogs, behavior, fear

I'm new to this site.

I have a question: my baby (my dog) got her tail caught in the screen door and she has been injuried, resulting in a wound. Now she is scared to come inside or to come near me and I don't know how to help her.

How should I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Best suggestion I've got:

Re-introduce yourself as you would to a Dog you've never seen before and that isn't sure it trusts you.Go outside, sit down, and give her a chance to come to you, with lots of space to retreat so she doesn't feel threatened. When she eventually does so, don't grab at her; make clear that you're happy to see her, possibly offer her a treat or two. Let her convince herself that you didn't mean to hurt her and she's still "your baby".

Then see if she can be persuaded to follow you back inside.

If she's willing to accept you as Mommy again, it'll be a lot easier to examine the wound, clean it, and if it's at all serious take her to the vet.

Answer (score -4):

Let her get hungry - she will come to food.  You, inside, or outside.

Most dogs are driven by food.

I had a dog that did not like his outdoor kennel so I started feeding him in the kennel and learned to like the kennel.

Comment: flagged as very low quality, please consider improving your answer or deleting it all-together